# Confuse about the date

Tags: calendar

From this [website](https://www.hebcal.com/converter?hd=14&hm=Nisan&hy=3793&h2g=1), I get:

> 14th of Nisan, 3793 = Fri, 1 April 0033

To make easier, assumed that the sunset is always exactly on 6.00 pm.
So, 14th of Nisan duration is from 6.01 pm to 6.00 pm 
and 1 April duration is from 00.01 am to 00.00 am

Abdul say :
*"today is April 1st 4 pm"*

What I would like to know :
At the moment Abdul say like that, is it 14 Nisan or 13 Nisan ?

I mean, 
if it's 14 Nisan, then around 3 hours more it's 15 Nisan 
if it's 13 Nisan, then around 3 hours more it's 14 Nisan

Any kind of respond would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advanced.

---

ADDITION:

I'm sorry as I think I need to give a reason for my confusion:
It's because I wander what if Abdul location it's not in Israel.

Based the answer from N.T, so:
because `if it's April 1st 4 pm then it's 14 Nisan 4 pm`
then (me conclude) `the Date in regular calendar is always 6 hours before then the Date in Hebrew calendar`.

So, if Abdul in Jerusalem at 6.05 pm (after sunset) say : "today is April first",
then the date in Hebrew calendar is 15 Nisan 6.05 pm.

I wonder how if Abdul (for example) in Auckland. 
Auckland is 9 hours ahead then Jerusalem.
So, if in Auckland at 6.05 pm (after sunset) Abdul say : "today is April first", but in Jerusalem is not sunset yet, it's still morning 9 am in Jerusalem.

So I wonder what is the date in Hebrew calendar when Abdul say *"today is April first"* in Auckland at 6.05 pm (after sunset) ?

Answer (score 4):

14 Nissan. You are right to notice that Hebrew dates and English dates never match exactly, because our day begins at sundown and English dates go by midnight. However, calendars go by the daylight where there is most of the overlap, and ignore the few hours difference.

Comment: This is a common convention as observed by this answerer, but any given calendar might pick a different convention.

Comment: But why would they? This way makes the most sense.

Comment: Maybe the calendar was developed for a Sefirat HaOmer app where all anyone cares about is what day it becomes at sunset of a given gregorian date.

Comment: N.T, thank you for your answer. As Double AA say, I wonder how is the Hebrew date when the sunset in some place is 9 hours ahead than in Jerusalem. Will there be a discrepancy in Hebrew calendar ? I mean like this : if in Auckland right after sunset is a new date 15 Nisan (April first) - then in Jerusalem (also April first) still morning, not experience the sunset yet, is 14 Nisan.

Comment: @karma. Yes that’s correct. The date changes everywhere at local sunset. Just like the secular calendar changes date everywhere at local midnight. So, to give another example, Auckland at 6am it’s April 2nd, at the same time as in Jerusalem it’s 9pm on April 1st. But in both places it’s now Nissan 15th.

Comment: N.T, thank you very much for your explanation. So, it can be different "international" date when the case is in your comment above, but it can be different Hebrew date when the case is in my previous comment. For example, continuing your example in the comment above : by the time April 2nd in Auckland is 7 pm, then it's **Nisan 16th in Auckland**, but it's still **Nisan 15th in Jerusalem** 10 am ... and in this case, now the "international" date is the same, April 2nd. Please CMIIW.

Comment: Yes, that's right.